# using awk to record certain column value every Nth row

Tags: awk, multiple-columns, rows

I have a file that has hundreds of thousands of data rows with 6 columns.

The first line that has the data starts at line 304. I am looking for an 'awk' command that can give me the value of column 2 after every 243 increase of lines. So the first value would be "row 304 column 2" and the second value would be "row 547 coulmn 2" and so on ...

Thanks

Comment: Please do add 3 simple things in your question. 1st- Sample of input, 2nd-sample of output. 3rd- Your tried code as efforts, that will make your question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each line read is split into fields: `$2` is the column 2

`NR` is the current line number of the line being read.

Give this a try:

```
awk 'NR>=304 && !((NR-304)%243) { print $2;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jay! exactly what am looking for.

I have this command that I want to combine with yours, which is :

awk 'NR> 242  {print $1}' file.txt | uniq

and I want to place them in two seperate columns and put them in a new file, any advice how to?

thanks again, appreciate it!

Comment: this is not clear. Maybe try to propose something, that we would comment.

Answer (score 2):

With the modulo operator:

```
awk '! (FNR < 304 || (FNR-304) % 243) {print $2}' file
```

Or a counter variable:

```
awk '++c == 304 {print $2; c -= 243}' file
```

Comment: Thank you so  much!
It works flawlessly!

 I have this command that I want to combine with yours, which is : awk 'NR> 242 {print $1}' file.txt | uniq and I want to place them in two seperate columns and put them in a new file, any advice how to? thanks again, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk, you can do this

```sh
awk 'NR==304 || NR==x{print $2;x=NR+243}' input
```

**Input:**

```
$ paste <(seq 10000) <(seq 10000) > input
```

**Output:**

```
304
547
790
1033
1276
1519
1762
2005
2248
2491
2734
2977
3220
3463
3706
3949
4192
4435
4678
4921
```

Comment: That command isn't GNU awk specific, it'd behave the same way in any awk.